# Groupby Percentage from total

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I am trying to group by the region and finding the percentage of product1 , product2, and product3 from the total product.

Here is the code

```
a = df_2018.groupby(['ISIC4_ARABIC']).agg({'product1': ['sum'], 'product2': ['sum'], 'product3': ['sum']})
```

So in the end i will have product1 , product2, and product3 as percentage of total product and the total product as the number.

below is the image of the data frame

[image]

Comment: Please provide your sample data as text, not images.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
cols=['produc1','product2','product3']
a[cols]=a[cols]/a[cols].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: why did you put product 3 out from product 1 and 2

Comment: It was a mistake, sorry

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
s = a.iloc[:, 1:]
a.iloc[:, 1:] = s.div(s.sum(1), axis='rows')
```

Output (`a`):

```
  region  product1  product2  product3
0     CA  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
1     MN  0.500000  0.250000  0.250000
2     OH  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
3     NY  0.714286  0.142857  0.142857
```

Comment: thank you Quang . but i want to get product1 , product2, and product3 as percentage and the total product as the number.

Comment: @AzizAlreshidi you're welcome. Plz consider upvote and accept the answer if it helps.